# Ionic ng-repeat problema com scroll vertical

Tags: ionic

Estou fazendo uma lista de cartões com ng-repeat no ionic, o problema é que ele buga o scroll vertical após um certo ponto (trava como se não houvesse mais conteúdo). Isso só acontece no Android, no Browser não.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/scofield25/pen/NxjmYP/

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">
      <div class="col col-50" ng-if="$index < movies.length">
        <div class="list card" width="100%">
          <div class="item item-image">
            <img class="movie-img" src="http://og.infg.com.br/in/12760791-e87-726/FT1500A/550/cristo-redentor.jpg">
          </div>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <strong>{{movies[$index].name}}</strong>
            <p class="movie-type">
              {{movies[$index].type}}
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-50" ng-if="$index + 1 < movies.length">
        <div class="list card" width="100%">
          <div class="item item-image">
            <img class="movie-img" src="http://og.infg.com.br/in/12760791-e87-726/FT1500A/550/cristo-redentor.jpg">
          </div>
          <a class="item">
            <strong>{{movies[$index+ 1].name}}</strong>
            <p class="movie-type">
              {{movies[$index+ 1].type}}
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Adicione o código diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: Pronto, código adicionado.

Comment: No exemplo no Codepen não apresentou erro. Mas tente usar `collection-repeat` ao invés de `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Provavelmente a versão que você esta testando do Android deve ser menor que 4.4 certo?
Se for tenta testar numa versão maior e vê se resolve.
Ainda não encontrei solução para isto(tenho o mesmo problema), então requisito do meu app é 4.4 >